# Limit of the principal square root of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

For $x < -1$
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to0^{+}}\left(1-x^2+2xi\epsilon+\epsilon^2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} = i\sqrt{\left|1-x^2\right|}
$$
Is this correct? Why/why not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify the meaning of $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for an arbitrary complex number $z$. If we make the convention that if $z$ is not a non-negative real number then $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ must lie in the upper half of the complex plane, then the mapping $z\mapsto z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is continuous on the complement of the non-negative part of the real line in the complex plane and so your statement follows from the fact that the expression to the right of the limit operator on the left-hand side of the equation is a continuous function of $\epsilon$.